# MongoDb + Java: no $db stored with DbRef?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java

Using mongo-2.8.0.jar, I want to get db-reference to an another db. But code (Groovy)

```
def ref = new DBRef(db,"mails",id)
println ref
```

Prints something like:

```
{ "$ref" : "mails", "$id" : "50211d8e44ae1f34b4f4b3bd" }
```

And no $db stored in database too!

How to force Java Mongo driver to save $db ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java driver does not support the optional $db field, as described in the MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/#dbref). Not all drivers support the $db field. The Java driver assumes that the collection is in the same database as the document that is storing the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The DBRef's DB object is stored as a private member of DBRef's parent class, DBRefBase, and is accessible with getDB(). You just need to call ref.getDB()

Comment: I wanna get db stored to database, not to use it in java code. If it's missed, I'm getting exception on fetching object with embedded reference with Morphia : (com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: The reference({ "$ref" : "mails", "$id" : "5021630744ae3176f5a34968" }) could not be fetched)

Comment: Morphia is trying to retrieve the referenced document automatically, but can't find it. Perhaps query the target database to make sure the referenced document exists. When Morphia is resolving references it will default to the current database, unless you specify it with the full namespace in the $ref field. try "$ref" : "dbname.mails"